# whole big array from heap to file without for loop in C++

Tags: c++

A big array on the heap, initialized like this:

```
 double* vx = new double[1024/8 * 1024 * 1024];
```

wants to be directly saved to a file like this:

```
file.write((char*)&vx, sizeof(1024 / 8 * 1024 * 1024));
```

This only writes the first value but the idea should be clear.

Comment: The `file.write` second parameter is the *number of bytes*, not the *number of double* elements.

Comment: As a site note, you probably don't want to manually use `new`/`delete` yourself. You can save yourself a lot of trouble by using an RAII-equipped class to manage the memory for you. Depending on your usecase, any of `std::vector`, `std::unique_ptr<std::array<double,128*1024*1024>>`, `std::unique_ptr<double>` might fit your bill

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`vx` is already a pointer. By taking its address again (`&vx`) you tell `write` to write the memory contents at the memory location where that pointer is stored rather than where the pointer points to.

Moreover, your second parameter is wrong. `sizeof( ...some integers ...)` is the same as `sizeof(int)`. It should be the number of bytes to be written. That is `number of elements * sizeof(double)`. Note that `sizeof` has no buisness in determining the number of elements in an array. You cannot retrieve the number of elements from the pointer `vx` and to query the number of elements from an array you would use `std::size`.

---

So many problems are caused by confusing arrays with pointers. `vx` is not an array. It points to the first element of an array. `write` needs the memory location of the first element, which coincides with the memory location of the array.

Comment: They tried to calculate number of bytes, but it resulted in `sizeof(int)`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen omg. too much coffee. I admit I didnt read the code carefully and only say eljays comment....

Comment: TBH, I was in the process of writing comment that it doesn't compile, so maybe it's just Friday afternoon effect ;)

Comment: indeed it is :) wooohoooo

Comment: right thanks, I forgot to remove the divisor which makes it the elementnumber. I know it's a pointer and thats's just the problem, I want to avoid using a for loop to write the values, I thought maybe it's possible to use the address and the fact that the whole array starts right there for this.

Comment: @Raiden Yes it is a pointer, but the wrong one. And ´the issue with `sizeof(1024 / 8 * 1024 * 1024)` is not about a divisor. `sizeof(1024*1024*1024)` is exactly the same value as `sizeof(42)`. I suppose you refer to `sizeof( array) / sizeof (array[0])` but thats wrong here  (and should not be used anywhere, because when it is right, then you should prefer `std::size`)

Comment: @Raiden sorry I am having difficulties to explain myself ;). My point is that `vx` *is* the address where the array starts, but `&vx` is the address where the address of the array is stored.